# how can i know why reconcile of controller is called on k8s

Tags: go, kubernetes, controller, reconcile

how can i know why reconcile of controller is called on k8s.

I use controller-runtime to implement my controller, recently, I always find some unknow reconcile loop, sometimes the 'reconcile()' is called several times in a short time. I can confirm that each reconcile return nil.
I want to know which object(add/update/delete) lead to reconcile function is called.How can I do this? kubectl debug? metrics?
Thanks!:)

[image]